# Gulp plugin for adding script tags

Tags: javascript, typescript, plugins, gulp

I need a plugin that would automatically add `<script>` tags to HTML files.
Now I use tsify and browserify to compile my typescript files and bind them into a single JavaScript file. It works fine, but for development and debug purposes it isn't convenient that all the code gets packed into a single file.

I don’t want to add `<script>` tags manually. Is there any solution for adding `<script>` tags to include all the needed .js files separately?

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is fine that everything is bundled into a single file. For debug and development purposes you can use sourcemaps. It is supported in both Typescript and Babel. You can easily view/debug your source code in Chrome in DevTools -> Sources.

Comment: Can you explain why -1?